# Setting detailTextLabel in TodayExtension's TableViewCell failed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I try to display a text in the `detailTextLabel` of the tableView in my today extension. The code seems to be correct, but I don't know why it's not displayed in the cell.

I set the text like in the normal tableView in the iOS app `(`        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test")`, but don't know why it's not working. Hope you can help me.

Comment: What type of your TableViewCell in Attribute Inspector -> Style ?

Comment: Style is set to Custom

Comment: Try set right detail for example

Comment: Yes now it works. Style Custom and Basic don't display detailTextLabels. Thanks for your help!

Comment: consider deleting this question if it is no longer relevant.

Comment: It would be better to add an answer to this question so others can benefit.

Comment: @alex_p If you write an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Attributes Inspector -> Style` to `Right Detail` for example to fix this problem

[image]